# How to render html documents for test driven development?

Tags: python, html

I have a system which processes complete HTML documents and fragments from within HTML documents. (Sub elements of a complete HTML document, for example a set of `<div>` tags.)

I want to test this system both by writing unit tests in code and by running manual test cases using message injection.

In both cases, I need a way to create and render (as text/strings) HTML documents.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

My first thought was perhaps something like Django or Flask could be used. I believe both of these are able to render HTML using a "template". I don't have a detailed understanding of how they work but iirc there is a way to do it. I don't know if a subset of either library can be used to create `str` instances containing the desired HTML.

## Here's an example of what a test might look like:

Here is just a sketch of some possible ideas.

### Input

```
<div>
  <div class="id">1234</div>
</div>
```

### Logic to be tested

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# exact logic unimportant, just an example
def extract_id(document: str) -> int:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_div, features='html.parser')

    div = soup.find_all('div', recursive=False)
    
    if len(div) == 1:
        div = div[0]

    div_id_attrib = div.get('id')
    if div_id_attrib is not None and len(div_id_attrib) > 0:
        text = div.text
        return int(text)
```

## Test Case

```
# template "div_template.html"
<div>
    <div class="id">#value</div>
</div>
```

```
# load html template from file
html_template = load_html_template("div_template.html")

dictionary_of_values = {
    'id': 1234,
}

output = render(html_template, dictionary_of_values)

assert extract_id(output) == 1234, 'test failed'
```

## Summary

It would be possible to implement some Python code to generate the `str` object which contains the required html for testing. But this is likely to be a manual and error-prone process.

Is there a way of implementing tests similar to the sketches above using Python?

Comment: Are you looking for recommendations on packages which would do this?

Comment: @possum No, because that would be against the rules

Comment: Have you tried using mako or jinja2? You don't need a web framework to render templates